# ng-repeat not working with resolved data?

Tags: angular

I am upgrading an app and passing data via a service to the controller which resolves it and passes it to the template.

The top binding shows the data but the repeat doesn't cycle thru them saying they are undefined.

what am I missing here?

controller code:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.stats.getCustStats()
     .then(custStats => this.customerStats = custStats.data)
     .then(error => console.log(error))
}
```

template code:

```
<div class="col-xs-6"># Customers :{{customerStats.length}}</div>
<!--<div class="col-xs-6"># Views :{{$ctrl.customerStats | sumOfValue:'views'}}</div>
<div class="col-xs-6"># Clicks :{{$ctrl.customerStats | sumOfValue:'clicks'}}</div>
<div class="col-xs-6"># Leads :{{$ctrl.customerStats | sumOfValue:'leads'}}</div>-->

<div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="customer in customerStats">
    <h3>{{customer}}</h3>
    <div class="col-xs-3"> Views : {{customer.views}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"> Clicks : {{customer.clicks}} </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"> Leads : {{customer.leads}}</div>
</div>
```

`customerStats.length` shows the length but the `ng-repeat` does not show and throws errors because it's undefined.

Comment: try this `<div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="customer in $ctrl.customerStats">`

Comment: That wont work, im upgrading an app so its half angular and half angularJS. the data gets passed because the top customerStats shows the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you are using the function ngOnInit. That's from Angular 2-4
So your ng-repeat won't work. Proper syntax:

```
<div *ngFor="let customer of customerStats;">
  {{customer.something}}
</div>
```

Also, your bootstrap is wrong. Cols should always be preceded by rows. Proper way:

```
<div class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let customer of customerStats;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">{{customer.something}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I know the bootstrap is wrong , i was in a hurry its for testing only. anyway thx this solved it. i already tried this as the first option but i forgot the let >< was getting confused between all the upgraded and downgraded components.

Comment: I also have a problem with using a custom filter with all these things but that might be a seperate question.